# Using the React Effect Hook using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to create a simple TODO app using React and Typescript but i am getting the "Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006"
i wrote the following code

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Container } from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import Todos from "./Components/Todos";
import TodoForm from "./Components/TodoForm";
const App=()=>{
  const[todos, setTodos]=useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const localTodos=localStorage.getItem("todos")
    if(localTodos){
      setTodos(JSON.parse(localTodos))
    }
  },[])

  const addTodos= async addtodo=>{
    setTodos([...todos, todos]);
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
  } , [todos]);

const markComplete=id=>{
  setTodos(todos.filter(todo=>todo.id !== id))
};
  return(
    <Container fluid>
      <h1>todo with local storage</h1>
      <Todos todos={todos} markComplete={markComplete}/>
      <TodoForm addTodos={addTodos}/>
    </Container>
  )

}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `markComplete` function has an parameter `id` that has no type defined. So the compiler defines it as `any`. Try using a type like `string` or `number`, depending what the `id` type is of a `todo object`. Like this:

```js
const markComplete = (id: string) => {
  setTodos(todos.filter(todo=>todo.id !== id))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your `markComplete` function is accepting an `id`, I assume this is of type `string`, therefore mark it as such -

`const markComplete = (id: string) => ...`

typescript has both implicit and explicit typing, with implicit, it will try and work out based on previous code which type to use, however it can't in your case, so is warning you that it is being marked at `any`.  If you *do* want to allow for implicit `any`, you can set the `noImplicitAny` property to false in your tsconfig.

To be fair, all of your code above is written as plain javascript.  I would expect to see a `type` or `interface` for a `Todo` and start to use that throughout, e.g.

`const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([])`

and

`const addTodo = (todo: Todo) => ...`.

you would then get the benefit of typescript, for example you would get an error if you tried to add something that wasnt a `Todo` to your `todos` array

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to add the following line to your tsConfig file:

```
   "noImplicitAny": false
```

This will generally allow to have no type which will be interpreted as "any". If you dont have this you need to add a type to everything you have.